# Postman 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: spring-boot, postman

[image]

I tried using postman to test my springboot project. When I sent the request, postman made a 503 error, but when I sent the request in the browser, it successfully got a response.

How to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the app, you're making a POST request but the browser would be making a GET request.

Comment: Sorry, I used GET at first, but it didn't work either.

Comment: You might also want to add the server-side code to your question so that folks can see what's going on. You're only showing one side of the story at the moment.

Comment: I believe that response is enough right? @Danny

Comment: Share the logs of spring boot, if it's throwing a 503 it is probably a service/configuration filter

Comment: It seems you blame Postman here. Click on `Code` under the Save button and select cURL. Try to run that curl command and see the response.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a unique direction. But I followed your instructions, but the result is still like this.

Comment: Check your hidden autogenerated message headers.  Make sure the Host header is checked off.  See my post, I had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69930832/web-version-of-postman-with-browser-agent-works-but-the-postman-desktop-app-and

Comment: Lately in postman using an alias name in local environment http requests is causing 503 Service Unavailable error, so just changing it to 127.0.0.1 solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I resolved it like this :
[Postman settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZFzv.png)
go to the top right of your postman window Settings > proxy > use the system proxy
for my case I added another proxy so I had to desable it when making a local api call. good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I resolved it.
please open IIS Server and select Application pools and check particular name and status. if status stopped go  to started. then you will go to check your post man.

IIS Server => Application pools => Status => started

[image: I had the same issue I resolved it]

Answer (score -1):

503 Service Unavailable clearly states the server is overloaded, you may be running out of memory. Try again or try to restart the server. The post method will say bad request only. So you should try restarting the server if it is yours, or retry after sometime if it is a 3rd party service.

And also can you check and make sure your postman proxy is turned off. Even that causes problems like these sometimes. Check that in proxy tab.

Comment: Thanks so much, but I tried  to restart the springboot project, it seems doesn't work.It seems to me is a Postman problem. This has always worked in borwsers, even in the Http Client of IDEA , but it failed in postman.

Comment: did you try turning off all proxies in proxy tab?

Comment: can you try once again with the IP 127.0.0.1:8081 instead of localhost

Comment: even try curling it.

Comment: Lately in postman using an alias name in local environment http requests is causing 503 Service Unavailable error, so just changing it to 127.0.0.1 solved it for me.